# Is it a correct procedure to link a Relationship Table with other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, relational-database, powerdesigner

I would like to know if it is right to link a relationship table with other tables. I tried it in PowerDesigner, but it give me a warning about it. However: I have two table called "Client" and "Staff" in Many-to-Many relations. In the given relationship table I linked two other tables in 1-to-Many realtions. The relationship table now has two primary keys (primary key of staff and primary key of client) and 2 foreign key. It's a correct procedure? I have this situation:
[image]

The warning message is:

> Category  Check   Object  Location
>   Table Index Index inclusion Index 'generate rent history.GENERATE_RENT_HISTORY_PK' includes 'GENERATE_RENT_HISTORY_FK'  ::generate rent history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's valid for a table to have a composite primary key which consists of two columns, and for each of those columns to be a foreign key. And it's valid to have other columns which are also foreign keys.

I'm not familiar with PowerDesigner, but I suspect the warning message isn't about the foreign key constraints, but concerns redundant indexes.

To support the PRIMARY KEY constraint, there's going to be `UNIQUE INDEX` on `(idstaff,idclient)`.

To support the FOREIGN KEY constraints, we would need an index with leading columns of `idstaff`, and another index with a leading column of `idclient`.

But an index on `(idstaff)` is *redundant*.

We already have an index with a leading column of `idstaff`... the primary key index.

As far as the table definition, these two indexes are sufficient to support the foreign key constraints referencing `staff` and `client`:

```
 PRIMARY KEY (idstaff,idclient)
 KEY generate_rent_history_IX1 (idclient)
```

There's no need to add an index like this:

```
 KEY generate_rent_history_IX4 (idstaff)
```

I suspect PowerDesigner is being instructed to generate that redundant index, and is issuing a warning that the index is not actually needed.

(I'm just guessing at the order of the columns in the PRIMARY KEY. If the columns are the other way around with `idclient` as the leading column, then we need the index on `idstaff` column, and the index on `idclient` column would be redundant.)

Comment: Sorry for the late,  but isn't it an error, right? if I export it to MS Access it works correctly?

Comment: ah, in your opinion is this database's part in the second normail form? I think yes (note that the relationship table represent the order of client, taken by the staff, in fact there are two primary key: idclient and idstaff. Foreign keys represent the orders of the client, written by staff)

Comment: To be more precise, the primary key of `generate_rent_history` contains *two* columns. It's a *composite* primary key. Those *two* columns are components of exactly *one* primary key constraint on the table.